# Using functions return values in an if condition javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a simple if conditional like so,

```
if (gl.Node.moveUp.call(this) && this.parent._currentScene()) {
    // Do something
}
```

Both functions return a boolean, does the condition get evaluated in order?

`gl.Node.moveUp` alters something within the object calling it, which I would still like to happen even if `_currentScene` returns false.

So in pseudo code if the condition output was something like

```
if (true && false) {

}
```

Would the call to `gl.Node.moveUp` still get executed and alter the calling object or because the overall condition evaluates to false does javascript do a roll back?

Would it be better to wrap it into two if conditions like below?

```
if (gl.Node.moveUp.call(this)) {

     if (this.parent._currentScene()) {

     }
}
```

Comment: You have 666 reputation score now, why not ask the devil? (sorry for non-constructive comment, could not help myself)

Comment: Should take you three seconds to figure this out with a simple test -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a9Hf6/), and no, the second function does not run if the condition fails after the first function has returned a boolean.

Comment: @adeneo That was not my question

Comment: Yes it was, if the first function returns true, the second function gets called, and whatever that function does, it does, there are no "rollbacks"!

Comment: @adeneo "Would the call to gl.Node.moveUp still get executed and alter the calling object or because the overall condition evaluates to false does javascript do a roll back?"

Comment: Again, there are no rollbacks in javascript, the function ***has*** to execute to return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first function returns false the second function will be called, otherwise it steps out our in the else block. Even the second parameter is `false` the first function will be executed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The second operand of a `||` or `&&` will only be evaluated if the first operand doesn't already determine the result. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11.